# Error with regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex

I need help with a regular expresion. I want get data from http://www.ambito.com/economia/mercados/ (price of "DÓLAR (OFICIAL)" and "DÓLAR (INFORMAL)").

I use that =

```
 $data = file_get_contents("http://www.ambito.com/economia/mercados/");
 $cadena= '/(?:<span class="m2">)?(.*)(?:<\/span><span class="m3">?(.*)<\/span><span class="m4">)?(.*)(?:<\/span>)/';


if ( preg_match($cadena, $data , $cap ) )
```

I get FALSE in the if because  I dont find Match

EDIT:

thank you very much. Now I read DOM's documentation then I resolve my problem with that code (I dont know if this is the best way).

```
    $domain = 'http://www.ambito.com/economia/mercados/';
 $html = file_get_html($domain);

 $ret_m3 = $html->find('span[class=m3]');
 $ret_m4 = $html->find('span[class=m4]');

 echo $ret_m3[0]."<br>";
 echo $ret_m4[0]."<br>";
 echo $ret_m3[1]."<br>";
 echo $ret_m4[1]."<br>";
```

Comment: Why not use [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)?

Comment: I dont use DOM because i dont know use that ;D if you can help me and get me code plz.

Comment: @user1736258 well, [the internet is glad to help you](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.ambito.com/economia/mercados/");
$cadena= '#<span class="m2">([^<]*)</span>\s*<span class="m3">([^<]*)</span>\s*<span class="m4">([^<]*)</span>#';

if ( preg_match($cadena, $data , $cap ) ) {
        var_dump($cap);
}
```

Ouput :

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(133) "<span class="m2">Dólar (Oficial)</span>
                <span class="m3">7,960</span>
                <span class="m4">8,010</span>"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "Dólar (Oficial)"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "7,960"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "8,010"
}
```

As mentionned, using regex is not the best way to parse HTML (xml) documents.

Answer (score 0):

As other people commented, you should use a DOM parser instead of regular expressions for getting information from HTML. Anyway, here is for getting the Dólar (Oficial) values, the other one should be as easy as this one:

```
/\<span class=\"m2"\>(?:.*)\<\/span>\s*\<span class=\"m3"\>(.+?)\<\/span\>\s*\<span class=\"m4"\>(.+?)\<\/span\>/
```

Groups 1 and 2 should be the values you are looking for.